# Link to Network Admin Broken After Switching to HTTPS

Tags: multisite, https

I am busy moving all sites to HTTPS (using ZeroSSL/Letsencrypt) on a Hetzner.de managed hosting server. I have this working for a single site but my **multisite installation** is giving me issues.

My main site (top-node.com) works without an issue (frontend and backend), however, I cannot log into the **network admin** options to install new plugins, etc. (kind of a deal breaker right there).

When I'm logged into the main site's admin backend, the link to the network admin should be https://top-node.com/wp-admin/network/. However, this is rewritten to https://http//top-node.com/wp-admin/network/ - there seems to be some (.htaccess) magic happening here.

In my quest to solve this, I have resorted to downloading the complete site and database and searching for any references of *http//* and other variations, but this is not stored anywhere.

I have also tried various .htaccess adaptations but this did not solve the problem either. Here is my current version:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm at my wits end, so I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What is your WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL defined as in your wp-config.php file?

Comment: They are not set at all in wp_config.php - it worked without?

Comment: Also, setting these, does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was removing `http://` from DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE in my wp-config.php.

before

`define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'http://example.com' );`

after

`define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com' );`

Answer (score 0):

For HTTPS rewrite, use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

For WordPress rewrite, use the appropriate one shown here: https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess . Go with the Basic one first, adjust if a subdirectory.

For the URLs used in the wp-options table, use the full HTTPS URL for your site (in two places). Entry in wp-config.php is not needed.